# Reading JSON Response in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have an angular controller called productImages which returns following JSON data:

```
{
    "Product_1":[
        {   "image_id":"12469",
            "name":"My Product 1 - Variety 1",
            "url":"\/\/mystorefront.net\/120\/small\/1911791794.jpg"
        },
        {
            "image_id":"12470",
            "name":"My Product 1 - Variety 2",
            "url":"\/\/drfuittf5cya9.cloudfront.net\/121\/small\/1911802897.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "Product_2":[
        {   "image_id":"122349",
            "name":"My Product 2 - Variety 1",
            "url":"\/\/drfuittf5cya9.cloudfront.net\/122\/small\/1911791794.jpg"
        },
        {
            "image_id":"123470",
            "name":"191123897.jpg",
            "name":"My Product 2 - Variety 2",
            "url":"\/\/drfuittf5cya9.cloudfront.net\/123\/small\/1911802897.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my angular code I have written:

```
<div ng-controller="productImages"> 
  <div ng-repeat="product in products">
    {{product.image_id}}
  </div>
</div>
```

When I run this the `ng-repeat div` gets repeated twice but product.image_id does not show up. If I do `{{product}}` instead or `{{product.image_id}}` I get the whole JSON printed.

How do I print this JSON in angularJS? Also, How do I get **Product_1**, **Product_2** printed?

Comment: Can you add some Javascript code example ?

Comment: Your JSON is not in the right syntax for a `ng-repeat` statement. You cannot iterate of properties in an object.

Comment: Please read the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties

Answer (score 3):

Your object `Product_1` seems to be an array which in turn has images.

I think you will need nested for loops to display the images

Answer (score 2):

You try to repeat over the properties of an object.
Accourding to the [documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) you'll have to use

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
```

each property of your object is an array so I think that something like:

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj">
   <div ng-repeat= "product in value">
      {{product.image_id"}}
   </div>
 </div>
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Use two loops for this as:

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.products = {
    "Product_1":[
        {   "image_id":"12469",
            "name":"My Product 1 - Variety 1",
            "url":"\/\/mystorefront.net\/120\/small\/1911791794.jpg"
        },
        {
            "image_id":"12470",
            "name":"My Product 1 - Variety 2",
            "url":"\/\/drfuittf5cya9.cloudfront.net\/121\/small\/1911802897.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "Product_2":[
        {   "image_id":"122349",
            "name":"My Product 2 - Variety 1",
            "url":"\/\/drfuittf5cya9.cloudfront.net\/122\/small\/1911791794.jpg"
        },
        {
            "image_id":"123470",
            "name":"191123897.jpg",
            "name":"My Product 2 - Variety 2",
            "url":"\/\/drfuittf5cya9.cloudfront.net\/123\/small\/1911802897.jpg"
        }
    ]
} 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
      <div ng-repeat="product in products">
          <div ng-repeat="item in product">
               {{item.image_id}}
          </div>
          <hr/>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how I can print "Product_1" and "Product_2"?

Comment: In <div ng-repeat="product in products"> you print as {{product.attribute}}

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON syntax is incorrect. If I understand correctly, each of our product has several varieties. It should be as follows:

```
{
    "Products": [
        {
            "Product": [
                {
                    "image_id": "12469",
                    "name": "My Product 1 - Variety 1",
                    "url": "//mystorefront.net/120/small/1911791794.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "image_id": "12470",
                    "name": "My Product 1 - Variety 2",
                    "url": "//drfuittf5cya9.cloudfront.net/121/small/1911802897.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Product": [
                {
                    "image_id": "122349",
                    "name": "My Product 2 - Variety 1",
                    "url": "//drfuittf5cya9.cloudfront.net/122/small/1911791794.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "image_id": "123470",
                    "name": "My Product 2 - Variety 2",
                    "url": "//drfuittf5cya9.cloudfront.net/123/small/1911802897.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And you HTML should be:

```
<div ng-controller= "Products"> 
  <div ng-repeat= "for oneproduct in Products">
    <div ng-repeat="for variety in oneproduct">
      {{variety.image_id"}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not tested this though...

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate on the object productImages because it's not an array.
You can iterate the objects "Product_1" and "Product_2".

If you want iterate the object productImage you have to write it ad an array.